# How do I use a package in composer that has the same name as another package?

Tags: composer-php

I have a rare case where I have two packagists in play here because I'm working on a Drupal Project. I have https://packagist.org and http://packagist.drupal-composer.org/.

The problem here is that they both define the package drupal/coder. One of them respects the composer.json, and the other does not, but generates one. I'm fixing to go create an issue over [here](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-parse-composer/issues) that tells them to respect the composer.json is one is available.

I would like to use the package from packagist.org, but since I define packagist.drupal-composer.org, I'm not able to.

Is there a way to identify a package from a specific source, or to redefine a repository that already has a package.

I tried to add

```
{
  "type": "vcs",
  "url": "http://git.drupal.org/project/coder.git"
}
```

in my repositories to no avail. Doing a `composer update; composer show` simply shows me the package from packagist.drupal-composer.org. Additionally, defining:

```
{
  "type": "composer",
  "url": "http://packagist.org"
}
```

Provides me with the same results.

My last thought is to define a "package" and point it at the repository with a different name but seems like a lame work around because then I have to maintain "versions".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes thats definitely a problem. But here is a workaround, just the package definition above packagist.drupal-composer.org to your composer.json.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packagist.org/p/drupal/coder.json"
    },
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://packagist.drupal-composer.org"
    }
]
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow :) - Nice and fast workaround with https://packagist.org/p/drupal/coder.json +1  This should be included in the Composer docs.

Answer (score 2):

1. You define Drupal's packagist as Composer type repo.
2. You define a git repo for the `drupal/coder` repo.

Both definitions go into the `repository` section.

Now: all packages are fetched from http://packagist.drupal-composer.org/, except `drupal/coder`.

Here you go:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "http://git.drupal.org/project/coder.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "packagist.drupal-composer.org"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "drupal/coder": "8.2.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definatly the more traditional way I would do this... what's the difference between "type": "git" and "type": "vcs". I don't see it on composer.org. Additionally, after adding the repository entry and doing `composer show drupal/coder 8.2.1`, I still get the drupal-composer specs.

Comment: Ok the trick is that repositories higher in the list take priority. Going to edit your answer so that the two are switched... and that will make it correct.

Comment: Type "git" is just more specific for this repository, because we know that it is a git repo. Type "vcs" will trigger the autodetection, repo fetch, check what kind of thing this is hg, svn, git. Here defining `git` instead of `vcs` saves a bit of time. Priority when higher in the list. That surprises me a bit, because the rule should be that any custom repository has priority over packagist/composer repository. But if moving the definitions around works for you, why not.. :)